# exclude subdomain from android app links - kotlin

Tags: android, android-deep-link, android-app-links

I have an application with Android App Links implemented

the domain has many subdomains
`login.example.com`
`shop1.example.com`
..
`shop23.example.com`
`chat.example.com` (and many more)

in Manifest file for host I have only `*.example.com`
`<data android:host="*.example.com" android:pathPattern=".*" android:scheme="https" />`

I want to exclude a single subdomain, but the only solution that I've found is to add each subdomain individually into manifest like this
`<data android:host=“@string/shop1_host”/> <data android:host=“@string/chat_host”/>`

is there any way to take advantage of `.well-known/assetlinks.json` file to do it ? in that file I have only code related to android app
`"target": { "namespace": "android_app", "package_name": "com.example", "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [ ... ] }`

I want to exclude `login.example.com`, providing a good and simple solution